# mysql failing to start with version 16.04.1

Tags: mysql

MySQL is failing to start on Ubuntu 16.04

Error code:

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start-post) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2016-11-29 15:13:28 EST; 28s ago
  Process: 4925 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 4922 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4925 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE);         : 4927 (mysql-systemd-s)
    Tasks: 2
   Memory: 580.0K
      CPU: 632ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─control
             ├─4927 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
             └─5014 sleep 1

    Nov 29 15:13:28 vmdb-master systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
    Nov 29 15:13:29 vmdb-master systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
===========================================
2016-11-29T20:53:54.626501Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)
2016-11-29T20:53:54.626576Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 2000)
2016-11-29T20:53:54.785332Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2016-11-29T20:53:54.785371Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2016-11-29T20:53:54.785490Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /mnt/raid0/mysql/vmdb-master.lower-test
2016-11-29T20:53:54.785542Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) starting as process 5291 ...
2016-11-29T20:53:54.788939Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /mnt/raid0/mysql/vmdb-master.lower-test
2016-11-29T20:53:54.788990Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /mnt/raid0/mysql/vmdb-master.lower-test
2016-11-29T20:53:54.791836Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2016-11-29T20:53:54.791887Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2016-11-29T20:53:54.791895Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2016-11-29T20:53:54.791918Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2016-11-29T20:53:54.791925Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2016-11-29T20:53:54.791931Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2016-11-29T20:53:54.792247Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2016-11-29T20:53:54.792376Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-11-29T20:53:54.794969Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 4G, instances = 8, chunk size = 128M
2016-11-29T20:53:55.097378Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-11-29T20:53:55.132818Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2016-11-29T20:53:55.142992Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
2016-11-29T20:53:55.143032Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
2016-11-29T20:53:55.143043Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2016-11-29T20:53:55.744170Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2016-11-29T20:53:55.744194Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2016-11-29T20:53:55.744207Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2016-11-29T20:53:55.744214Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2016-11-29T20:53:55.744223Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2016-11-29T20:53:55.744291Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2016-11-29T20:53:55.744301Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2016-11-29T20:53:55.744627Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
--------------------------------------------
```

the directory where the files are located are set to 777 and it is still complaining that it cannot write.

Comment: could apparmor be causing a problem?

Comment: It is apparmor causing the problem.  trying to find out why, nothing changed now this is keep mysql from running.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is mentioned here:

**2016-11-29T20:53:55.142992Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable**

You should use sudo to start mysql service or make sure that the user account which is starting the mysql service has write access at the location where innodb_system

Comment: Yep, starting that way and the directory and files within are mysql:mysql

Comment: chmod 777 on the directory too, same error

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER:

had to edit /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin/mysqld and add the actual location of the mysql installation.  Don't know why it did not have this information in before or how it was running with out it but it was apparmor DENYING mysql's access to it's own directory.